# Oracle IF Statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following query which is not working when I use IF statement. When I run only select statement its giving me the result I want.

what should I change on this query?

I am open to other suggestions like using 'CASE' instead of 'IF' if that would be easier!

```
DECLARE
operacija VARCHAR2 := 'z';
BEGIN
IF operacija = 'z' THEN


(select (MIN_QUANT + (50/100) * MIN_QUANT) as MIN_QUANT, 
        (OPT_QUANT + (50/100) * OPT_QUANT) as OPT_QUANT,
        (MAX_QUANT + (50/100) * MAX_QUANT) as MAX_QUANT 
from my_table
where PRODUCT_CODE = '01' and CODE = '123' and FLAG = 'C');
END IF;

END;
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must select values into variables and assign value to variable after begin block, like

```
DECLARE
   operacija     VARCHAR2(200);
   v_min_quant   NUMBER (20, 2);
   v_opt_quant   NUMBER (20, 2);
   v_max_quant   NUMBER (20, 2);
BEGIN
   operacija :='z';

   IF operacija = 'z'
   THEN
      SELECT (MIN_QUANT + (50 / 100) * MIN_QUANT),
             (OPT_QUANT + (50 / 100) * OPT_QUANT),
             (MAX_QUANT + (50 / 100) * MAX_QUANT)
        INTO v_min_quant, v_opt_quant, v_max_quant
        FROM my_table
       WHERE PRODUCT_CODE = '01' AND CODE = '123' AND FLAG = 'C';
   END IF;
END;
```